# why does the javax.naming.NamingException occur here?

Tags: java, jdbc, naming

when i run the following :

```
package NonServletFiles;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.*;

public class GetTagsFromDatabase {

public GetTagsFromDatabase() {

}

public String[] getTags() {

    String tags[] = null;
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/photog"); // <<----- line 23
        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
        String sqlQuery = "select NAMEOFTHETAG from tagcollection";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();

        int i = 0;
        while(set.next()) {
            tags[i] = set.getString("NameOfTheTag");
            System.out.println(tags[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tags;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new GetTagsFromDatabase().getTags(); // <<----- line 43
}
}
```

I get the following exceptions :

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jdbc/photog' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at NonServletFiles.GetTagsFromDatabase.getTags(GetTagsFromDatabase.java:23)
at NonServletFiles.GetTagsFromDatabase.main(GetTagsFromDatabase.java:43)

Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation 
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.getComponentId(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:873)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:742)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:172)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
... 4 more
```

I don't know the reason for this exception,all other servlets that need to connect to the database with the url `java:comp/env/jdbc/photog` work fine.

Comment: Could you post code of a servlet for which this connection works?

Comment: @Amit Bhargava why do you need that ?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to find some differences between the two that would explain why it doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 12):

The stacktrace hints that you're using Glassfish. Remove the `java:comp/env/` part. It's the default JNDI context root already. Only in Tomcat you need to specify it explicitly. Also, you should be invoking this in webapp context, not as a plain Java Application with `main()`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, do you really need to get the `DataSource` *everytime*? I'd create a helper class which obtains it only once on webapp's startup or in a static initializer. It's application wide and threadsafe. Only the `Connection` indeed needs to be obtained (and closed! you're not closing it, so you're leaking DB resources) everytime you need to fire a SQL query.

Comment: Why does Tomcat alone need the `java:comp/env` part? I figured it the hard way.

Comment: @asgs: No idea. Tomcat guys decided it so. Tomcat is not a full fledged Java EE container anyway.

Comment: @asgs: you may find this (old) tutorial useful http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html (mainly Tomcat targeted, yes, but it should give you the idea of doing basic JDBC properly). Or you could just go for JPA if you're already using Glassfish or any other full Java EE container. No JDBC boilerplate code anymore.

Comment: i have been using `java:com/env/` with glassfish and that has been working fine. For example i invoke a helper class method that makes a table ,with the url in the look up the same as in my question. After removing the `java:comp/env/` though i don't get any exception,i don't see the output either. Instead an input stream is opened in in the output! The reason i used main was just to test if i get the output fine